# How to check if I can spam email with my VPS

Tags: vps, spam

Last time, I did have a problem with my VPS regarding being used as a spam mail server. Now I just did the backup and how can I test that I can use my server to spam or not ?

Comment: This is both too broad and a duplicate, but basically, the important thing is that you disable smtp if you're not using it, and if you are, restrict what IPs/domains you accept mail from, to avoid being an "open relay."

Comment: Hire an admin or read a book. As in: We are not here to teach basics of system administration - beginner questions and questions showing clearly you lack basic understanding are not welcome here as per FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to prevent being an open relay. You can check if you are one e.g. with [this tool](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I do know the tool but I'm not so clear that how can it be possible since last time I didn't install any mail server, just a simple wordpress installation. Can you help me explain ? Thanks

Comment: It's quite possible that you installed a mail server as a dependency of the packages required to run Wordpress. You need to check which packages are installed and secure them. If you can't do this, don't run a server.

Comment: thanks that would be the case. But do we have any way to test if a server can be used to spam ?

Comment: Check the list of installed packages. Again, if you don't know how, turn off the VPS and switch to a hosted  Wordpress provider.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but my goal is to install a complete VPS myself :)

Comment: You need to learn the fundamentals (lots of them) before using a public server. Start learning on a VM on your desktop system and understand the basics. Why? One example: Running an open relay on your VPS doesn't hurt only you but also the spam victims, the provider and his other customers because they will get blocked fast by other systems because you didn't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether SMTP like Sendmail or Postfix service is running or not. If it is running and it is not required please the stop the service. If it is required and want to check for open relay, then try to connect to SMTP (Prot 25) from the outside of your network and try to send the email. If you could succeed then you are in trouble. Then you need to restrict the IPs/Subnets you accept the email from. May this help you.